# How to reverse infinite loop direction on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I have made this infinite banner. So far, banner goes from right to left, and the loop pause while I hover the dot. What I need tho, is reversing banner direction while hovering the left dot (only that one).
If I stop hovering, I need it to go back to its previous direction (not to its previous position), any help would be appreciated since I don't have many JS skills.
Thank you

JS

```
$(function () {
  var first = 0;
  var second = 100.0;
  var started = true;
  var move;
  const initialSpeed = 30
  const onHoverSpeed = 10
  let speedUp = false;
  let direction = 'left';


  function moveBanner() {
    move = setInterval(function () {
      first -= 0.1;
      second -= 0.1;
      if (first <= -100.0) {
        first = 100;
      }
      if (second <= -100.0) {
        second = 100;
      }
      $('.first').css('left', first + "%");
      $('.second').css('left', second + "%");

    }, 10);
  }
  moveBanner();

  $(".dot").hover(function () {
    speedUp = true;
    if(started) {
      clearInterval(move);
      started = false;
      if ($(this).hasClass('dot--left')){
        direction = 'right'
        console.log('left dot', 'should go:', direction);
      } else {
        direction = 'left';
        console.log('right dot', 'should go:' direction);
      }
    } else {
      speedUp = false;
      direction = 'left';
      console.log('should go:', direction)
      moveBanner();
      started = true;
    }
  });
})
```

HTML

```
<div class="banner">
    <div class="dot dot--left"></div>
    <div class="dot dot--right"></div>
  <div class="loop first">
      <p>
        Stuff here
      </p>
  </div>
   <div class="loop second">
      <p>
        Stuff here
      </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.banner {
   overflow: hidden;
   position: relative;
   height: 100vh;
}

.dot {
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  z-index: 6;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 65px;
  max-width: 140px;
}

.dot--right {
  right: 180px;
}

.dot--left {
  left: 180px;
}

.loop{
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 5;
    color: yellow;
}

.first{
   background-color: red;
}

.second {
  background-color: blue;
  left: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, use **mouseenter** and **mouseleave** events instead of hover as hover will trigger both of them. Then, to reverse the direction increment the values instead of decrementing them.

In your moveBanner function:

```
if(direction == 'right'){
    first += 0.1;
    second += 0.1;
}else{
    first -= 0.1;
    second -= 0.1;
}
```

Not sure if this is exactly what you're looking for but might come in handy: https://jsfiddle.net/mj46vtgr/

Comment: Thank you for your response. I will try to adapt your answer to my exact needs!

Comment: No worries, all the best.